# panel.setAttribute("mode","waterfall");

Tags: javascript, polymer

This is my core header panel

```
<core-header-panel mode="waterfall-tall">
```

When I want it to be in waterfall mode instead of waterfall-tall I do this

```
var panel = document.querySelector('core-header-panel');
panel.setAttribute("mode","waterfall");
```

It changes the mode correctly and the element behaves like a waterfall, but the element does not shrink to its original size and stays tall. How can I shrink the element again to a normal waterfall size in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

core-header-panel should really handle this for you when the `mode` is switched.
It should do cleanup and remove any `tall` class it sets on child nodes. Filed a bug here: https://github.com/Polymer/core-header-panel/issues/11

A workaround would be:

```
coreHeaderPanel.querySelector('.tall').classList.remove('tall')
```

BTW, you don't need to use `setAttribute()`. `mode` is a published property of core-header-panel, which means you can directly update it as a JS property:

```
coreHeaderPanel.mode = 'waterfall';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the class "tall" from the core-header, if I'm not mistaken.

```
var header = document.querySelector('.tall');
header.className = "core-header";
```

Comment: I tried it but it seems to stay the same size? Could it be waterfall-tall does set something else?

Comment: Also it does not work the other way around by starting with a normal watterfall and add a tall class `panel.className = "tall";` to make it bigger.

Comment: Just tried it in the console on the demo page. Ebidels workaround should do basically the same.